# date_select in form fails with "<field> is invalid"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this template,

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Insurance Expiry : </label>
  <%= date_select f, :insurance_expiry, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

and migration has,

```
def change do
  create table(:buses) do

   # snipped

    add :insurance_expiry, :date, default: Ecto.Date.local

  end
```

and in db model,

```
 schema "buses" do

 # snipped

   field :insurance_expiry, :date

 end
```

Debug Info on create action,

```
[info] Processing by BusMan.BusController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "PDkIZycHTRJsEzwOEBJRXxo6MVIFJgAAHla/FI4Y5PQxTYdk/XakNg==", "_utf8" => "✓", "bus" => %{"bus_no" => "138", "chassis_no" => "nTHSNTH", "engine_no" => "RCHR989", "insurance_expiry" => %{"day" => "1", "month" => "10", "year" => "2019"}, "models" => "NTHRCG898", "reg_no" => "TN21W0613", "year_of_registration" => "1990"}, "format" => "html"}
```

form submission fails with :

```
Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below:

    Insurance expiry is invalid
```

I just want to input a date, Is `date_select` is what I need or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as [José Valim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588267/jos%C3%A9-valim) corrected, using `Ecto.Date` rather than `:date` correctly solves the issue, and doesn't require explicit casting.

---

It looks like the date being passed to the create function is a map. Prior to inserting it, try casting it to date with

`Ecto.Date.cast(%{"day" => "1", "month" => "10", "year" => "2019"})`

I could imagine code that looked something like

```
selected_date = %{"day" => "1", "month" => "10", "year" => "2019"}
  |> Ecto.Date.cast
  |> Repo.insert!
```

Comment: `insurance_expiry_map = bus_params["insurance_expiry"]
    {:ok, insurance_expiry_date} = Ecto.Date.cast(insurance_expiry_map)

    updated_bus_params = %{bus_params | "insurance_expiry" => insurance_expiry_date}

    changeset = Bus.changeset(%Bus{}, updated_bus_params)`
I also changed `:date` type to custom `Ecto.Date` in schema. That did it :)

Comment: You don't need to cast it explicitly. The error was the fact you used `:date` and not `Ecto.Date`. I will raise better errors for this soon.